# Indexes update in DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I've been working with LSI and GSI in DynamoDB, but I guess I'm missing something.

I created an index to always query by the latest results without using the partition key only other attributes and without reading the entire items, only those that really matter, but with the GSI at some point my query returns data that are not up-to-date; this I understand due to the fact of eventual consistence described in the docs (You may correct me if I'm wrong).

And what about LSI? Even using the ConsistentRead, at some point my data is not being queried correctly, and the results are not up-to-date. From the docs I thought that LSI where updated syncronized with its table and with the ConsistentRead property set I'd always get the latest results, but this is not happening.

I'm using a REST endpoint (API Gateway) to perform inserts into my dynamo table (I perform some treatments before the insertion) so, I've been wondering if this has something to do with it: maybe the code (currently Java) or DynamoDB is slow to update but since in my endpoint everything seems to work fine I perform another request too fast or if I have to wait a little longer to interact with the table because the index is being updated, although I have already tested waiting longer I'm receiving the same wrong results. I'm a bit lost here.

This is the code I'm using to query the index:

```
 QuerySpec spec = new QuerySpec()
                .withKeyConditionExpression("#c = :v_attrib1 and #e = :v_attrib2")
                .withNameMap(new NameMap()
                        .with("#c", "attrib1")
                        .with("#e", "attrib2"))
                .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
                        .withString(":v_attrib1", attrib1Value)
                        .withString(":v_attrib2", attrib2Value))
                .withMaxResultSize(1) // to only bring the latest one
                .withConsistentRead(true) // is this wrong?
                .withScanIndexForward(false); // what about this one?
```

I don't know if the maven library version would interfere, but in any case the version I'm using is the 1.11.76 (I know there are a lot of newer versions, but if this is the problem we'll update it then).

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for quite some time and some other tests I, finally, figured out that the problem was not in DynamoDB indexes, they are working as expected, but in the Lambda functions.

The fact that I was sending a lot of requests, one after another, was not giving the indexes time to remain updated: Lambda functions execute asynchronously (I should have known), and so the requests received by the database were not ordered and my data was not properly updated. So, we changed our implementation to use Atomic Counters: we can keep our data updated no matter the number or the order of the requests.

See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters